# DrPython won't execute

Tags: python, wxpython

I have successfully installed Python 3.6.2, and I have successfully installed wxPython using:

```
pip.exe install --upgrade --pre -f https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/snapshot-builds/ wxPython
```

I've downloaded and "installed" DrPython:

```
C:\Program Files\Python\Python36>7za x "c:\Install\Tools&Utilities\DrPython_3.11.4.zip"
```

When I invoke: pythonw.exe drpython\drpython.pyw, I get nothing.

When I invoke: python.exe drpython\drpython.py, I get:

```
C:\Program Files\Python\Python36>python drpython\drpython.py
    File "drpython\drpython.py", line 697
   except Exception, e:
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

If I fix that with "except Exception as e:" I then get errors about the Print command requiring parentheses.

Comment: Is that tool compatible with Python 3.x?

Comment: I don't know. I didn't see anywhere where it said it wasn't. However with the trouble I'm have it may not be.

Comment: And its windows again. I would recommend install Anaconda and use spyder.

Comment: This too looks like way more than I need. What I'm ultimately looking for is a simple Scripting/Debugging environment for Python. Much like VBSEdit for VBScript and ISE for PowerShell. I'm a SysAdmin and I do a lot of scripting, not full blown "projects". For now I guess IDLE will have to do.

Comment: The traceback for the `print` comes from within the library or your own code? If the former, it sounds like the library is not compatible with python 3.

Comment: errors show that this program is in Python2. You could try to convert into Python3 using program `2to3` ((installed with Python3). If DrPython works only with Python2 then it can be old and use only older wxPython so you can get other problems.

Comment: Roganjosh: the trace back from the Print error is from within DrPython. From other comments it looks like DrPython is not yet available for Python 3.x

furas: I'll try the conversion just too if it works. I'll report back.

Thanks all.

Comment: Most DrPython "Seemed" to convert OK. With that I saw no errors. However there were still some errors when trying to fire it up. I'm still way to knew at Python to go into an in depth dive in trying to figure this out.

For now IDLE it is. I can only hope that the DrPython folks do a proper upgrade to Python 3 in the not too distant future.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: There are lots of other text editors that you can use and a lot of them are free. I would just use one of those.